# Can we choose next master node in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, high-availability, mirroring, rabbitmqctl

Can we prefer one slave node to be a master than another slave node? Assuming I want to choose next master node to be a node with the minimum masters or with the maximum resource available if current master node fails. Is it possible to organize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look the `x-queue-master-locator` policy.
Read here:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html

> Queue Master Location Every queue in RabbitMQ has a home node. That
>   node is called queue master. All queue operations go through the
>   master first and then are replicated to mirrors. This is necessary to
>   guarantee FIFO ordering of messages.
>
> Queue masters can be distributed between nodes using several
>   strategies. Which strategy is used is controlled in three ways,
>   namely, using the x-queue-master-locator queue declare argument,
>   setting the queue-master-locator policy key or by defining the
>   queue_master_locator key in the configuration file. Here are the
>   possible strategies and how to set them:
>
> Pick the node hosting the minimum number of masters: min-masters Pick
>   the node the client that declares the queue is connected to:
>   client-local Pick a random node: random

I also suggest to read this post: 
https://www.erlang-solutions.com/blog/take-control-of-your-rabbitmq-queues.html

This should help you